# Access Haivision SRT statistics from ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg, srt

I have been successfully using ffmpeg to stream using the Haivision SRT protocol enabled, I need to access the SRT statistics as described here https://github.com/Haivision/srt/blob/master/docs/API/statistics.md

Can anyone help me to understand how to access these statistics from an ffmpeg commadline streaming SRT.